# Upload a file and Send Data same time using IFormFile and HTTPClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient, .net-6.0, iformfile

I am trying to upload a file and in the same time send some data to the server as a json object using a xunit test using HttpClient.

Api Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(IFormFile? attachement, [FromForm] EmailIncomingDTO emailIncomingDTO)
    {
        //Logic Goes here
        return Ok();

    }
```

Unit Test

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendDataWithAfile(string url, EmailIncomingDTO contactUsPayload)
    {
        var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("abc.png");

        ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileData);

        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");


        form.Add(byteContent, "attachement", Path.GetFileName(ImagePath));
        form.Add(new StringContent(jsonPayload, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "emailIncomingDTO");

        //var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var client = this.Factory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, form); //Throws 400

        return response;
    }
```

For some reason, when I try to send both text and media same time, it throws 400 error, but If I send either image or file separately after modifying the controller, gets 200.

Comment: You need a multipart body which is MIME.  MIME attachments starts with two dashes on a new line.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)  Error 400 is a bad request.  Your body has errors.  The server has to be designed to receive the multipart.

Comment: you can't mix two mimetypes. when you are sending file you are already using "multipart/form-data". you need to individually set the fields of your EmailIncomingDTO to form. attaching as string won't work.

Comment: you can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/file-upload-to-web-api-with-different-http-clients-in-c-ae123555ef49)